# Dynamically create class in ng-repeat, and associate properties

Tags: css, angularjs, class, properties, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to run an ng-repeat on an array of players in a football team. Each player has a `position` property which evaluates to `gk`, `df`, `mf`, or `fw`. I want it so each position is associated with a color.

- GK: Green,
- DF: Blue,
- MF: Orange,
- FW: Red.

```
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line">

            <div>

              <div class="pos">
                  <p class="{{player.position}}">{{player.position | uppercase }}</p>
              </div>

            </div>

        </md-list-item>
```

At the moment I am using a literal angular expression on the `position` property for each player which dynamically generates the class (as well as the following string output in the paragraph tags) which I have hardcoded as a color style in the stylesheet.

This works, but I feel like there must be a slicker solution.

### Additionally...

I want to take a country code, for example `countryCode: "it"` and associate the output of {{countryCode}} with a full text string, "Italy", so I don't need to write out:

```
{ countryCode: "it", countryName: "Italy" }
```

...for each player. These two will always be associated (as with any country), so it seems pointless to write both out every time.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: why you are not satisfied with this solution? it's a working one.

Comment: Because just like the second, similar issue below ('Additionally...), I have to use the identical string to indicate class as the html text output: in this case, 'gk', or 'mf' (or whatever). I would like the option of outputting 'Midfielder' whenever the 'mf' value is found in the 'position' property. Just as I would like 'Italy' to be outputted when the 'it' value is found in 'countryCode' property.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a function that will return you the value required?

```
$scope.getPlayerClass = function (playerPosition) {

    switch (playerPosition) {

        case 'gk': return 'Green';
        ...
    }
}
```

while calling it just like you do now:

```
<p class="{{ getPlayerClass(player.position) }}">
```

The same principle could be used for the country. If you need to use it in more than one place, move it to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the position, I am not sure I understand your question, you could define a map in your controller and map there whatever info you want. And use it like:

```
<p class="{{positionsMap[player.position].class}}">
```

For the countries, you could define a variable italy, and use it in each player, like this you don't repeat the same code. The same could be done for the positions. E.g.:

```
var italy = { countryCode: "it", countryName: "Italy" }
var gk = {class: 'green', name: 'Goal keeper'}
var player1 = {position: gk, country: italy}
var player2 = {position: gk, country: italy}
```

In this last case, to use it in the html it would be:

```
<p class="{{player.position.class}}">{{player.position.name | uppercase }}</p>
```